# Tap on to activate button

Tags: android, kotlin

I want a button (myButton) and an EditText (myText) to be enabled and even shown on the activity only when I tap on a particular area (where the button is placed even though the button is not visible at this point of time).

On launching the app, these two elements are not enabled nor visible to the user. After tapping on the place (where the button is located), or anywhere on the activity will also be OK, for 3 times both the button and editText should show and be enabled. How can I get it done?

I am on Android Studio using Kotlin.

Comment: Please show your code so far and view xml

Comment: Since I do not know how to do this at all, action on tapping, I have not coded anything for this purpose. I have just created a new project with an activity, a button and an editText on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a possible solution in Java and then I used Android Studio to convert the `MainActivity.java` in Kotlin. But I will post both the Java and Kotlin source code and also the xml file.

The application has only one activity with a Button and an EditText that appears when the user tap somewhere in the activity three times.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
// gen with Android Studio
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var button: Button? = null
    private var editText: EditText? = null
    private var count = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText)

        val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)

        constraintLayout.setOnClickListener {
            if(count < 4) count++;

            if (count == 3) {
                button!!.visibility = Button.VISIBLE
                button!!.isEnabled = true

                editText!!.visibility = EditText.VISIBLE
                editText!!.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText =  findViewById(R.id.editText);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(count < 4) count++;

                if(count == 3){
                    button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    button.setEnabled(true);

                    editText.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);
                    editText.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```